# RegEx to replace all the double quotes to single quotes in side parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a single liner regular expression which should convert all the double quotes to single quotes which are present in side the parenthesis.

**Ex:**

`<span onclick="javascript:myfunction("param(s)1", "param(s)2")"`

I want the above one to be converted to

`<span onclick="javascript:myfunction('param(s)1', 'param(s)2')"`

I'm novice in Regular Expressions. Please help!

Comment: Because the parentheses can be nested, you cannot do that in a regex.

Comment: You would have to write your own parser. Regex can only parse regular languages. It is not good enough to handle balancing of brackets.

Comment: You should replace or escape them _before_ content is rendered into the double quotes (`=""`). I assume you use some server-side script.

Comment: The OP should be able to solve this with a regex, because he doesn't care about the nesting, just whether it's inside any parens or not. Something like the following Perl expression, although ugly, I think would work: s/(\(.*)\"(.*\))/\1'\2/g . I don't know enough JavaScript to render this into an actual answer.

Comment: To clarify -- I don't mean that you /should/ solve it this way, I agree with @MarcellFülöp and others that asking this question probably means you're going down a path that'll make your life harder in the long run. But, technically, I think you /could/.

Comment: @AndyMortimer I think given the example nesting brackets is important to the Sriram. This is why the example has brackets around the s after param.

Answer (score 0):

A function that will do this is:

```
function replaceQuotes(inputString)
{
    var output = '';
    var inbrackets = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++)
    {
        var currentChar = inputString.charAt(i);
        switch (currentChar)
        {
            case '\"':
                if (inbrackets > 0)
                    output += '\'';
                else
                    output += '\"';
                break;

            case '(':
                inbrackets++;
                output += '(';
                break;

            case ')':
                inbrackets--;
                output += ')';
                break; 

            default:
                output += currentChar;
                break;
        }
    }
    return output;

}
```

If you are wanting to process full HTML you will nead something more sophistocated than this.

Answer (score -1):

It seem that you really want to replace double quotes inside double quotes, what about this:

```
function replace_inside_quotes(str) {
  var regex_quotes = /"(.*)"(.*)"(.*)"/;
  while(regex_quotes.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(regex_quotes, '"$1\'$2\'$3"');
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: This will have a big performance issue if the string gets too long. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html